# only root mysql user can access WordPress

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress

I have recently encountered a problem where only root users or global privileged users have access to **WordPress**.

If I start wordpress with a normal user, it gives:

> "Error establishing a database connection"

and debug mode reports nothing.

Probably after I edited `my.cnf`

this is `my.cnf` setting:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 50M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
init_connect='set autocommit=0'
log="/var/log/mysql/sql.log"

#maybe I edited them also
#autocommit=0
#innodb_file_format = Barracuda
#innodb_file_per_table = 1
#innodb_large_prefix
#skip-networking

character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: what changes do you done?

Comment: the "normal" user is not correct created or has not all necessary right. Try to login via mysql client to see if you can access all Schemas

Comment: I already did, and mysql user can access to database. Thats why so strange.

Comment: I kind of remember, I changed mysql setting, for ActiveRecord to be able to work utf8mb4.

innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix


before it had this error, thats why.

 Mysql2::Error: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `unique_schema_migrations` ON `schema_migrations` (`version`)